# Is it possible to configure dashcode to support https datasource?

Tags: templates, https, xmlhttprequest, dashcode

I am using the Web template in dashcode. I want to change the datasource specification from http to https but I don't know how to specify username and password.

I see in /Parts/core/net/XHR.js, one can make https requests by specifying the user and password options but I dont know how to hack it in dashcode. It wouldn't let me edit XHR.js nor do I know how to define these local variables.

Comment: I have found a workaround. Don't know if it is the best method or not. First, when I configure the datasource, I have to specify https://user:ppassword@mysite.com/... and do a datasource refresh. Then try again without the user:password@ string. Save and deploy the project and access the project through https. Then I will get a prompt on my iPhone for username and password and my web page will work properly.